# Replacing variable in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a string

```
var DisplayString = "I am having VAR_1 value in box, i have to change to VAR_2, then to VAR_3, then to VAR_4";
```

I need to put for loop where VAR_ will be replaced by NEW_VAR_ ,Where number remains same.

How could i do that in jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var DisplayString = "I am having VAR_1 value in box, i have to change to VAR_2, then to VAR_3, then to VAR_4";
DisplayString = DisplayString.replace(/\VAR_/g, 'NEW_VAR_'); // this will replace all occurances of VAR_ to NEW_VAR_
alert(DisplayString);
```